# skinning a creature

Tags: rigging, bones

I am trying to skin the creature for a student who is having trouble. Every time I try, nothing happens. I am not sure if it is parented correctly or not and if that is the reason why it isn't work. I have been trying to get it to work for days and am stuck.  I copied the steps it says to do as well as the students work. Any help would be appreciated on how to fix it and get the student to the next step.

http://www.pasteall.org/blend/34459

Skin the Left Thigh

The second part of skinning is to assign the bone to the part of the body. Complete the following steps to assign the left thigh bone.

Right-click the character to select it and deselect the bones.
Switch to Edit mode.
Left-click the Vertex Select mode button.
In the Object Data mini-window, in the Vertex Groups menu, left-click UpperLeg.L.
Under Vertex Groups, left-click Select.
You’ll see an orange outline on parts of the left side. Press the B key and use Box Select mode. Hold down the B key and drag over all of the orange vertices using the left button on your mouse. Then press the Remove button. Then press the A key in the 3D View window to deselect everything. Press the B key and use Box Select mode. Hold down the B key and drag over the UpperLeg.L bone. 
TIP: You may need to repeat this step to get all the vertices selected.
Under Vertex Groups, left-click Assign.
Press the A key to deselect everything.

Answer (score 1):

The steps are excessive and lead to confusion. The first part wants you to remove vertices from the group that you don't want deformed by the bone, you don't have any extra vertices assigned to vertex groups so can skip the first part.

The second part is what you want to do -

> Then press the A key in the 3D View window to deselect everything. Press the B key to *[start]* Box Select mode. *[left click and]* Drag over the UpperLeg.L bone. TIP: You may need to repeat this step to get all the vertices selected. Under Vertex Groups, left-click Assign. Press the A key to deselect everything.

So you want to select all the vertices near the Upperleg.L bone that you want to move with that bone. You can also press <kbd>C</kbd> to paint select vertices, use the scroll wheel to increase/decrease the size of the circle you select with, press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to exit paint select mode. Once the vertices are selected, ensure you have Upperleg.L selected in the vertex group list (also check that the weight slider is at 1.0) and click the assign button. Now if you go into pose mode for the armature, moving the Upperleg.L will move the specified vertices with it.

Repeat for other bones.

I would recommend you have a look at [weight painting](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/sculpt_paint/weight_paint/index.html#weight-paint) for an easier method to what you are doing.

Comment: Thank you so much! I believe I got it to work and will be sending to my student. You are the best!